# How to let the output being printed on the interactive shell with subprocess

Tags: python

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen("pwd")
<subprocess.Popen object at 0xa7692cc>
>>> subprocess.call(["ls", "-l"])
0
```

I have tried the above command in Python interactive shell and expect to see the output
inside the shell environment. However, it ends up with just some return values.

What should I do in order to let the return results printed inside the shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'd help to read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) first.

```
p = subprocess.Popen('pwd', stdout = subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate() # returns (stdout, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

Cat Plus Plus is right, however, if you prefer the `call` function, you can also do this like so:

```
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.call('pwd', stdout=sys.stdout)   # outputs results of `pwd` to stdout
```

Comment: `import subprocess, sys
subprocess.call('pwd', stdout=sys.stdout)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 480, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 626, in __init__
    errread, errwrite) = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 983, in _get_handles
    c2pwrite = stdout.fileno()
AttributeError: PseudoFileOut instance has no attribute 'fileno'`

Comment: What do you mean? It seems like I cannot run the solution provided by Adam.